# Downgraded 22.04 -> 20.04, Ubuntu won't save user settings

Tags: settings, downgrade

I had a working AMD64 based Ubuntu computer w/ 22.04.   I had /home on a separate drive (from OS).   I downgraded 22.04 -> 20.04.   (Erase 22.04 and install 20.04, not a downgrade in place - a fresh install of 20.04)    After the fresh 20.04 install, edit fstab and remounted /home.    No problems, works as expected.

However, I can't get display related settings to work.   e.g.

- with NVIDIA driver loaded (tried several) - it recognizes my 2nd monitor but won't apply the settings (it flashes)
- I tried `chown` on `/home/<my user>`
- I tried adding another (`sudo`) user - same results
- if I run `$ sudo nvidia-settings`, I see:

```
(nvidia-settings:6568): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:36:40.622: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 10:36:40.677: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 10:36:40.677: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 10:36:40.700: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 10:36:40.700: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 10:36:40.700: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes
```

Comment: Your mistake was reusing the home folder. In most cases you can't just transplant a `/home` folder from one system to another. There are typically dozens or hundreds of configuration files in the home folder used by almost all of your software. These config files would be set up for the old system not the new system. It's more likely you can reuse home when the version/flavour is identical. But when you move to an older release, many things are not backwards compatible. Don't reuse the entire home folder, just copy what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I think you are completely correct.     This rabbit hole got a lot worse.     Known programs would not work - I couldn't get back to a firm foundation and eventually reformatted my /home and started from scratch.    My conclusion - Nmath is right, give it up; start over